# Using FileReader in a non-main method

Tags: java, parsing, csv, methods, program-entry-point

I can read a CSV file into my Java **main** method using the code below.

What I want to achieve is to be able to use the below code in a method that is *not* my **main** method. I want to be able to call this method from my **main** so that I can read a CSV file without having all this code cluttering my **main**. How do I do this?

FYI the CSV file has 2 columns of doubles, hence the use of the `double [][]`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    double [][] data = new double [100][2];    
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Username\\Java\\Test2\\First\\src\\Program1\\prac.csv");
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    BufferedReader bufRdr  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = null;


    //read each line of text file
    while((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null && row < data.length) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            //get next token and store it in the array
            data[row][col] = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
            col++;
        }
        col = 0;
        row++;
    }

}
```

Comment: We generally ask that you at least try to solve the problem before coming here, and to explain what that attempt entailed.

Comment: I don't think that `void` returns any value.

Comment: @ChrisBode I'm new so my attempts have just been silly and would waste everyone's time.

Answer (score 1):

Define a custom class called CSVReader -

```
public class CSVReader {

    public List<List<Double>> read (File file) throws IOException {
        List<List<Double>> data = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();    

        BufferedReader bufRdr  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = null;

        //read each line of text file
        while((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
            List<Double> row = new ArrayList<Double>();

            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                //get next token and store it in the array
                row.add(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
            }

            data.add(row);
        }

        return(data);
    }
}
```

then, in the main -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Double>> data;
    String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Username\\Java\\Test2\\First\\src\\Program1\\prac.csv";
    File file = new File(fileName);

    try {
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader();
        data = reader.read(file);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {

        // handle your exception
    }
}
```

Notice that I have used `List`s instead of arrays to read the data. This is much cleaner than using a two-dimensional array - I don't need to perform any bound checks anymore, nor I have to increment array indexes etc. You can read [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683), Item 25 - *prefer lists to arrays* - to learn more about the benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Simply move it into a new method:

```
public static double[][] readData(String fName){
    double [][] data = new double [100][2];    
    File file = new File(fname);
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    BufferedReader bufRdr  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = null;


    //read each line of text file
    while((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null && row < data.length) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            //get next token and store it in the array
            data[row][col] = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
            col++;
        }
        col = 0;
        row++;
    }

    return(data);
}
```

Being static it can be called from main without instantiating the class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is quite easy regarding to your code. You simply create another method called readCSV and return the data, then you can call readCSV in your main method. The code inside readCSV is exactly what you are doing now in your main method.

BTW, I notice that you don't close your reader after it finish its work and you are trying to return a value in your main method while the return type of main should be void, i.e., nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    double[][] data = readFile("C:\\Users\\Username\\Java\\Test2\\First\\src\\Program1\\prac.csv");
}

public static double[][] readFile(String filepath) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    double[][] data = new double[100][2];
    File file = new File(
            filepath);
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    BufferedReader bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = null;

    // read each line of text file
    while ((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null && row < data.length) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            // get next token and store it in the array
            data[row][col] = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
            col++;
        }
        col = 0;
        row++;
    }

    return (data);
}
```